# Is possible to get column names and table data by providing table name dynamically as input in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to get table data and column names by providing table name dynamically.

Below is my sample code.

```
Model class:

@Getter
@Setter
public class Test {
private String tableName;
private String whereCondition;
private List<Object[]> resultList; //list added for result set
}
```

Repository query:

```
public  List<Object[]> getTarget(String tableName, String condition){

String sqlQuery=" SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" "+condition+ "";
    List<Object[]> list = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery).getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

Here I am able to get only table data not column names. Is there a better way for above scenario and to get column names. Please suggest.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: you can use index to get column names. i.e from your question, list.get[0][0], list.get[0][1], list.get[0][2]. Something like this.

Comment: tried above but not working, list.get(0)[0] getting only first column value from table data not column name.

Comment: i just gave you example. You have to do that via loop. Also why do you need column names?

Comment: I Have to show both column name and table data in UI , for select query data.

Comment: You can get column names using this query in mysql : SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';

Comment: I am able to get the column names using this query, I need to test further on my conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this: `ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();`

and for Colum name get: `resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(1);`